# The get function data is reporting empty info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery.get() function to return data coming back from an embedded web server.  The data comes back in variables in this format(`<Nb_var00>`). The information is being placed in a table.

This is my get() function:

```
$.get("table_test_v00.html",function(data,textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
   var time=$(data).filter("#variable2").text();
   var temperature=$(data).filter("#variable1").text();
   $('td#variable1').text(temperature);
   $('td#variable2').text(time);
 })
```

Problem:

If I am using IE's debug tool and place a break point at $('td#variable'), I see that
time = "", instead of the actual time.  If I look at the return data this is what it 
has:

`<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"><meta http-equiv=\"Pragma\"content=\"no-cache\"><meta http-equiv=\"Expires\"content=\"-1\"><title>table_test</title><script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js\"></script><script src=\"Ajax.js\"></script></head><body><table border=\"1\"><tr><td id=\"variable2\">13:47:54</td></tr></table></p></body></html>`

as can be seen, time should have: 13:47:54, not "", can someone see what is going on?

by the way, if I switch from placing the information from a table `<td>` to `<p>` then information
displays correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` doesn't traverse when looking for elements that match a selector.

I prefer the context selector for this situation:

```
var time = $('#variable2', data).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "find" instead of "filter".